# Robo Reviewing of the first degree

Tags: support, review-queues, review-suspension

Why am I getting "Robo Reviewing of the first degree" message upon clicking review queue?

[image]

Previously I never saw any message like this. Can any one tell me why this happening with my account? Is my account suspended for reviewing new post?

Comment: Whether that verdict is justified or not, a bit more detail would certainly be appropriate, yes. ;-)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Apologies, it was my mistake. I wasn't aware that the message I put in was visible to you, so I just had to fill *something* in. (Had I known, I would have explained it better in my message)

If you like, I can contact you privately to explain my decision.

Comment: @Madara I did not understand the problem. can you please explain me why this happened?

Comment: @DhavalPatel did you consider re-checking your review history? ([it's public](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3506946/dhaval-patel?tab=activity&sort=reviews))

Comment: _@Madara Uchiha_ Well, new mods seem to make mistaken actions ;-) ...

Comment: @DhavalPatel You hardly ever reject in your reviews, it looks like you apparently blindly approve everything. I counted only a handful of rejects in your entire review history.

Comment: @DavidG I have rejected few reviews doesn't mean that I have blindly approve everything. you can hardly find few reviews that are rejected by community and accepted by me.

Comment: @DhavalPatel Just because other robo-reviewers also got it wrong, doesn't mean that you got it right. For example, you approved [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10366342) which is someone adding code to an answer. That kind of edit should not be allowed.

Comment: @DavidG I will take care of this next time. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidG To be fair, I'd also approve that one specifically. It improves the answers without changing its *meaning*.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It may be good, but I'm personally very reluctant to approve those things in case they change the intent of the answer (unless it's a CW). I would much prefer to leave a comment.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha For example, this [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) pretty much sums up my philosophy on this.

Comment: @DavidG nothing in that Meta post suggests that the edit you guys are arguing about is bad. The "Do" list is not intended to be exhaustive and the change made doesn't touch any of the points on the "Don't" list.

Comment: Could've been worse, Madara. Sounds like bad UI in the mod tools; giving someone a mistaken impression that their remarks are private when in fact they aren't is a pretty solid recipe for offence and embarrassment. At least you didn't write "user is a robo-reviewing scoundrel who deserves to be thrown off a cliff" or something.

Comment: @MarkAmery That post says *Don't change the code logic or functionality*, pretty sure that covers it.

Comment: @DavidG arguably, yes, but I think fixing minor bugs is surely intended to be allowed. Fixing syntax errors is explicitly in the "Do" list, after all, but code with and without a syntax error clearly has different functionality!

Comment: @DavidG: Fixing details in code vs in words isn't really important. As long as you don't change the meaning of the answer, or the intention of the code samples, editing is fine.

Comment: @MarkAmery (and Madara) For clarity, I'm not saying the change made was bad, it looks perfectly valid to me (but I don't write C++ so don't really know). Also this is not a syntax error, it's an entirely new line of code. Personally I would have added a comment than an edit, and certainly not an edit that would have entered the review queue.